# Use of colon after class name in c++

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

This is a header file extracted from a blackberry 10 helloworld program.

```
#ifndef ApplicationUI_HPP_
#define ApplicationUI_HPP_

#include <QObject>

namespace bb
{
    namespace cascades
    {
        class Application;
        class LocaleHandler;
    }
}

class QTranslator;

/*!
 * @brief Application object
 *
 *
 */

class ApplicationUI : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app);
    virtual ~ApplicationUI() { }
private slots:
    void onSystemLanguageChanged();
private:
    QTranslator* m_pTranslator;
    bb::cascades::LocaleHandler* m_pLocaleHandler;
};

#endif /* ApplicationUI_HPP_ */
```

I am confused about the colon operator right after the class name declaration.

```
class ApplicationUI : public QObject
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It means that `ApplicationUI` inherits all methods and member variables from the class `QObject`.  The use of `public` means that the public methods and members of `QObject` are also public in `ApplicationUI`.

Comment: so, is that colon another name for `extend` keyword?

Comment: No it's not, because there is no such keyword in C++.

Comment: oh, it seems that I confused it with java. and it also supposed to be `extends` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The class listed after the : is what the class ApplicationUI inherits from.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code snippet here:

```
using System;

namespace ProgramCall
{

class Class1
{

    public int Sum(int A, int B)
    {
        return A + B;
    }

    public float Sum(int A, float B)
    {
        return A + B;
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    public int Sum(int A, int B, int C)
    {
        return A + B + C;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Just a inheritance from the class1 to class 2 in simple way of doing it, i hope it helps some one!